# I/O Memory Mapping

Tags: io, cpu, hardware, bios, bus

I am reviewing the essentials of I/O, and while I think I understand most of what's going on, I'm still confused as to how either physical addresses or separate ports are mapped to individual devices. Does the computer poll the bus on system boot, assigning addresses to devices one by one, or are there fixed addresses that are loaded into memory somewhere? If this is done via the BIOS, how is this memory layout information relayed to the operating system?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

(this question has been asked and answered before, you should search first)

depends on the platform, you were not specific

some systems, some peripherals in those systems, are hardcoded by the chip/system designers.

for pci(e), as defined by that, you enumerate the bus(es) searching for attached peripherals, and those peripherals configuration spaces (which are defined by the peripheral vendor per their needs) indicate how many and how big they need.  For an x86 pc, the bios does this enumeration not the operating system.  for other platforms it depends on that platform it may be the bootloader or operating system.  but someone has to take the available space (basically hardcoded essentially for that platform knowing the platform and what is used already) and divide it up. for x86 it used to be just one gig that was divided up in the 32 bit days, and still happens on some systems, but for 64 bit systems the bioses open that up to 2gig for everyting, and can place that in a high address space to avoid ram (ever wonder why your 32 bit system with 4gig of dram only had 3gig usable?).  naturally a flat memory space is only an illusion, the windows asked for by the pci peripherals can be small windows into their space, video cards with lots of ram for example.  you use the csrs to move the window about, kind of like standing in your house looking out a small window and physically moving side to side to see more stuff through the window, but only the size of the window at any one time.

same goes for usb, it is enumerated, the busses are searched and the peripherals answer.  with usb though it doesnt map into the address space of the host.

how the operating system finds this information is heavily dependent on the type of system.  with bios on an x86 there is a known way to get that info, I think you can also get at the same info in dos (yes dos is still heavily used).  for non pcie or usb the operating system drivers have to find the peripherals or just know, if the platform is consistent (address of the serial ports in a pc) or have a way of finding them without harming other devices or crashing.  there are the cases where the operating system itself did the enumeration.  or the bootloader if that is the place where enumeration happened.   but each combination of bootloaders and operating systems on top of various platforms may each have their own different solution, no reason to expect them to be the same.

okay you did say bios and have a bios tag, implying x86 systems.  the bios does pci/pcie enumeration at boot time, if you dont setup your bios to know that your operating system is 64 bit it may take a gig out of your lower 4Gig space for the pcie devices (and if you set for 64 bit but install a 32 bit operating system, then you are in trouble there for other reasons).  I dont remember, but would assume there are bios calls the operating system can use to find out what the bios had done, should not be hard at all to find this information.  Anything not discoverable in this way is likely legacy and hardcoded or uses legacy techniques for being discoverable (isa bus style search for a bios across a range of addresses, etc).  the pcie/usb vendor and product id information tell the drivers what is there and from that they have hardcoded offsets into those spaces to complete the addresses needed to communicate with the peripherals.